# How to disable a function in Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am learning  Azure and specificially the Java serverless  functions that has been recently introduced by the MS team.

I  have developed a simple API as per their documentation. It works fine. But I want to disable it. As per their documentation, when i update the "disabled" to true, I am not seeing the API being disabled. I am still able to invoke it.

The sample function.json

```
    {
  "scriptFile" : "..\\myfunction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "com.xxx.myfunction.Function.hello",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "name" : "req",
    "direction" : "in",
    "authLevel" : "anonymous",
    "methods" : [ "get", "post" ]
  }, {
    "type" : "http",
    "name" : "$return",
    "direction" : "out"
  } ],
  "disabled" : true
}
```

Here is the steps that i followed to disable my function:

changed the function.json  disabled to true.  Click "Save" and then click "Run". I was able to get the response as 200 OK. What am i missing.

Comment: `I am still able to invoke it.` Does it means that works correctly?

Comment: Yes Tom. It is working correctly.

Comment: It seems that not working for java azure function, but it works correcly for C#  Azure function.

Comment: Any updates now?

Comment: I have posted the  observation with MSDN forum. WIll let you know once I hear back from them.

Comment: @mack OK. Waiting for your reply. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the Functions , you will be displayed with list of functions and option to disable and delete.[image]

Comment: I am able to see that the function is disabled even in my case. But When I am invoking the API, I am still able to get the response. So I am not sure what it means by "disabled"

Comment: We would be able to invoke but we get a http response with status 404. I tried with a C# based Http Function and when invoked after disabling we get 404 status.

Comment: Not for my case when I did with Java..  I am not sure where and what is missed

Answer (score 0):

I tried to disable my java azure function via two methods below:

***Portal manage :***

[image]

***Function.json setting :***

[image]

The results of both tests are all can be accessed normally as same as your test .

[image]

Then I learned from this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400963/how-to-enable-disable-azure-function-programmatically) that we can configure `functions array` in the `host.json` to specify which functions can be executed.

I ensure my `host.json` is an empty {}. However , the result of my test is also normal access.

Per my experience, Azure function for Java was released not long and it is experimental phase. I guess this is a bug and I suggest you submit a related feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions).

Hope it helps you.