# Disable Azure Function from an instance of the Azure Function

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function that reads from an Event Hub and updates an Azure SQL DB.  If the Azure Function cannot connect to the Azure SQL DB (i.e. incorrect password), I want the Azure Function to be disabled and the Event Hub not to change the checkpoint.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: I guess you should not have invalid password error ?? Otherwise you can deal with transient error (i.e. network problem) by implementing a retry strategy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Enable/Disable Azure Function programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400963/how-to-enable-disable-azure-function-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is best handles with Azure Logic Apps since it is a more orchestration oriented question with a possible workflow, I would not recommend disabling the azure function but creating several and handling the orchestration with logic apps with an error flow or custom error handling.